# Refrigerator Knocks

Tags: plumbing, appliances

I have an older refrigerator (~10 years?) that came with the house I bought 2 years ago.

It's always made occasional noises, which I chalked up to the motor and/or ice maker starting.

Lately, the noises are more frequent and sound like a loud metallic gong. I think it's coming from the water line, but I don't see any obvious problems.

Any idea what could be causing this, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Loud metallic gong? Sounds worrisome. When it starts making this noise, listen carefully to see if you can tell where it is coming from. The compressor or compressor motor is the most obvious thing I can think of, or maybe one of the fans. If it is a fan, hitting against some other part, that may be an easy fix - replace the fan or nearby part. If it is the compressor, that is a major fix best left for a repairman who can reseal the coolant system after the replacement. The compressor motor might be user replaceable, depending on how it is built. 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet you're hearing one **clong** once in a few hours. It's a thermal effect of the coolant as it works and it can flex the pipes.

You basically need a refrigeration mechanic to look at it, ideally someone who knows that brand of fridge. It might be loosing coolant and anything involving coolant system repairs usually requires a licensed worker.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford it, you may be better off replacing the refrigerator anyway. Newer models are far more efficient and can [pay for themselves](http://www.soundmoneymatters.com/replace-refrigerator/) in a couple years. When we got a new refrigerator with an ice dispenser I think it paid for itself in a year just because us kids weren't opening the freezer door every 30 minutes to fill our glasses with ice.